# d3.js parallel coordinates line thickness issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use different line width for different axes for parallel coordinates plot using d3.js

It works fine only if its in strictly decreasing order (for eg: `lineWidth=10` for 1st axis, `lineWidth=5` for 2nd axis and `lineWidth=2` for 3rd axis). But if the values are like (`lineWidth=10` for 1st axis, `lineWidth=2` for 2nd axis and `lineWidth=5` for 3rd axis) then for both the second and third axis the line thickness is 5, which is the greater value after a smaller one always overrides the smaller value. Is there any way to handle this issue? Your help is much appreciable.

Below is some code snippet which I'm currently working on.

```
if (i == 0) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
} 
else {          
    if(i == 1) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    }           
    if(i == 2) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    }               
    if(i == 3) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    }
    var cp1x = x - 0.55*(x-x0);
    var cp1y = y0;
    var cp2x = x - 0.45*(x-x0);
    var cp2y = y;
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

For the above code the line width is 10 for all the axes.

If I use `ctx.beginPath()` before every if statement, then the line thickness is working fine. But unfortunately the lines drawn between axes are shifting its position (only half-lines are being drawn)
Thanks in advance.

[If I use `ctx.beginPath()` at every if statement then this is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPqen.png)

Comment: So what do you want it to look like?

Comment: I want the same but the lines are not full between the axes. I want full lines to be drawn between different axes, not just half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x,y);
```

before every if statement. That way each iteration will be a new path and you will move to the correct position to start each line.

Comment: If I move the above 2 lines to every if statement, then the lines are drawn between axes are being drawn only half. Half of the space is empty and other half of the space has lines between the axes.